# Requirements.txt from local archives

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

How to add the modules in `requirements.txt` from local archives?
I wanted to add the below modules in `requirements.txt`, but from local directory

```
Awswrangler
Pyyaml
Boto3
Pandas
```

How specify the `whl` files in this case in `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example in [`pip` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#example):

> ```
> # It is possible to refer to specific local distribution paths.
>
> ./downloads/numpy-1.9.2-cp34-none-win32.whl
> ```